# Is there a way to use Conditional Rendering within List Rendering (v-for) in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using List Rendering (v-for) in my project to print each item in my array to show information on a series of books.

However, I am trying to use conditional rendering within this loop, in order to print a number of `li` elements that contain the book's category tag.

I do not want the `li` to be painted in the DOM if there is no data stored in my array. For example, for the first book, Moby Dick, the `ul` for the book tags would just contain two HTML list items.

How can this be done? I have the following so far ...

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="book in books">

        <div class="item">
            <div class="item-bd">
                <h2>{{ book.title }}</h2>
                <ul class="book-tags>
                    <li v-if="">{{book.tagOne}}</li>
                    <li v-if="">{{book.tagTwo}}</li>
                    <li v-if="">{{book.tagThree}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    books: [
        {
            title: "Moby Dick",
            tagOne: "Kids Book",
            tagTwo: "Fiction",
            tagThree: ""
        },
        {
            title: "Hamlet",
            tagOne: "All Ages",
            tagTwo: "Shakespeare",
            tagThree: "Classic"
        }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: Put the tags in an array instead and use the exact same mechanism (`v-for`). If you want to stick to three fixed tags, just use `v-if="book.tagOne"`. The fact that this is happening inside a `v-for` list doesn't matter one bit, afaik.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you Chris. I guess I was missing the book.tagOne etc inside conditional tag. I will also look at how to use an array as it must be a more DRY method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, if you want to keep three `<li>` items then simply you can check if respective tags exist or not as below:

```
<ul class="book-tags>
  <li v-if="book.tagOne">{{book.tagOne}}</li>
  <li v-if="book.tagTwo">{{book.tagTwo}}</li>
  <li v-if="book.tagThree">{{book.tagThree}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the problem I have is that if i change one property ( lets say book.tagOne) , the component does not re render .